# create user that has very limited permissions that can launch startx

Tags: startx

Could someone help me with a procedure to create a user that would have the least amount of permissions, no sudo access. That would be able to launch startx from a command line boot on raspbian-stretch, and run chromium.

Comment: That user needs to be in the group *tty* so it can open the VT for X. `useradd -G tty *username*`

Comment: @Janka Are you sure about that?  I would be surprised if I had never done this on a Debian system; Fedora does it [via PAM](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_console), although I notice there is no `pam_console.so` module to be found on Debian.  Searching Ask Ubuntu for "startx" implies to me there is no problem with this.  I suppose it doesn't matter much, but I'd try without first if keeping the user's permissions minimal is the goal.

Comment: It's what *startx* complains about when started as an ordinary user – no access to /dev/tty0.